Lock the Settings app?
I want to buy a Samsung phone, and I want to know if I can lock the Settings app with Secure Folder? Just want to use a Private DNS and lock it somehow this way by locking the Settings.

Hi, we have some related questions regarding this: How to lock some parts of Settings?, Is there a way to disable access to certain Settings components?, How can I disabled/lock certain settings components

Thank you @Andrew T. I bought a Samsung A16 but still cannot lock the Settings with Secure folder.I installed an third party applock within Secure folder but i don't have the option to lock Settings.
